# What are the steps to Solve $N \cdot \log_2N = 10^6$ algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I can write code that can solve it by just going through every integer but what are the steps to solve it with basic algebra. I seem to end up in a circular fashion of just writing it in terms of other things.

Comment: If you mean "Solve $N\log_2(N) = 10^6$," then please format this as `$N\log_2(N) = 10^6$`

Comment: @amWhy thanks the first link for formatting did not have it listed that way

Comment: I suspect there is no algebraic solution.

Comment: N is gonna be one huge number! Given $$N\log_2 N = 10^6$$ $$N^N = 2^{10^6}$$ $$N^N = 2^{1,000,000}$$ where 1 million = 1,000,000

Comment: This isn't an algebraic method, but you could use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). That would be much faster than trying every integer up to the solution.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley:  Not so huge.  Note that $N \lt 10^6$.

Answer (score 2):

$f : x\mapsto x \log_2x$ clearly is a strictly increasing countinuous function over $[1,\infty)$ since both $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto \log_2x$ are and are positive on $[1,\infty)$. Given that $f(1) = 0$ and that $\underset{+\infty}{\lim}f = +\infty$, the intermediate value theorem enables us to know there is a unique solution to:
$$
(E_a) : f(x) = a, a\in [1,\infty)
$$
Let $g : x\mapsto x \ln x$ to make calculaions easier. Similarly to what was previously said, $(E'_a) : g(x) = a, a\in [1,\infty)$ has a unique solution $x\in[1,\infty)$. Note that the solution to $(E'_{a\ln2})$ is the solution to $(E_a)$.

Then, as SmileyCraft thought, this is a plain use case of Lambert W function which is defined as the reciprocal of $w \mapsto we^w$. We have $x\ln x = a$ so $e^{\ln x}\ln x = a$ and $\ln x = W(a)$ and $x = e^{W(a)}$ which yields $x = \frac{a}{W(a)}$ (because, by definition $W(a)e^{W(a)} = a$).

We thus solved $(E'_a)$ for all $a\in [1,\infty)$:
$$
x \ln x = a \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{a}{W(a)}
$$
Then, given what was said previously:
$$
x\log_2x = a \Leftrightarrow x =\frac{a\ln 2}{W(a\ln 2)}
$$
Algebra will not get you much further than that.